# replacing columns in matrix from existing matirx R

Tags: r, matrix, random, sample, normal-distribution

I want to ask you a quastion how to replace some percentage of columns in Y matrix with columns form X matrix using function sample ?
So I have two matrixes X and Y and I want to replace for example 20 percent of columns (randomly) form matrix X to matrix Y using sample ? 
Please do you have any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (20% of m1 is replaced by m2 of the same indices):

```
m1 <- matrix(1, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
m2 <- matrix(2, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)

s  <- sample(1:length(m1), length(m1)*0.2) 
m1[s] <- m2[s]
```